# Code Coverage and Ternary Operators

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage, pytest, coverage.py

Consider we have this function under test located in the `module.py`:

```
def f(a, b):
    return (a - b) if a > b else 1 / 0
```

And, we have the following test case in the `test_module.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from module import f


class ModuleTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_a_greater_than_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(f(10, 5), 5)
```

If we run tests with `pytest` with the enabled "branch coverage" with the HTML output reporting:

```
pytest test_module.py --cov=. --cov-branch --cov-report html
```

*The report is going to claim 100% branch coverage with all the "partial" branches covered*:

[image]

But, we clearly have not covered the `else 1 / 0` part at all.

Is there a way to improve reporting to see the non-covered parts of the ternary operators?

Comment: Unlike the keyword version the operator version of `if` / `else` is not a control structure but a boolean operation. The actual control structure is hidden in the implementation of the operation, out of the sight of coverage. I agreed that it would be a good idea to have that implemented into the `coverage` package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Branch coverage can only measure branching from one line to another, since Python's trace facility currently only supports per-line tracing.  Python 3.7 introduces some bytecode-level tracing, but it would require significant work to make use of it.

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/509 is an issue about this.

Comment: Now that Python 3.7 is in pre-release, shouldn't the referenced issue be reopened (I ask because I see you are the maintainer)? PS. "opened" != "solved right away", but it is surely an important feature, no?

Comment: It would be better to discuss the issue on the issue, no?